# Remove Header and footer from a .txt Import

Tags: vba, text, import

I am importing a text file which is basically a text conversion of a pdf. My first cell contains Header. The logic that I am using

1. Capture first cell as header
2. Iterate through cells and find the next Instance of Header
3. Cell above that is footer
4. Delete the two cells
5. Additional check, if header and footer are the same

Is there a faster way of solving the problem. Takes lot of time for bigger text files.

```
Dim lrow As Long
Dim Header As String
Header = Cells(1, 1).Value
lrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lrow
Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
If WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cells(i, 1).Value)) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(Header)) Then
If WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cells(i + 1, 1).Value)) <> WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(Header)) Then
Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
Cells(i - 1, 1).Value = ""
End If

End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use the find method

[Find Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

So you can find the header and footers

```
Worksheet.cells.Find(header.value)
```

Comment: 1. At some places header has non-printable characters so I have to use clean function first
2. Cell above header is footer which also needs to be deleted
3. Can you help me plug it in the code. 
Learning VBA here

Comment: dim headerCleaned as string
headerCleaned= WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cells(i + 1, 1).Value)
Worksheet.cells.Find(headerCleaned.value)

Comment: With Find and replace I can delete the header, but how do we delete footer in this case. It's a multi - page doc. Header and footer will come at multiple times. And Footer can be anything depending on file type. However, It will always come a cell above Header